cement balcony cleaning
Would love to know if anyone has found a solution to keeping a not-flat or even balcony clean?
I have two balconies, both are un-even so the little “pock marks” collect a lot of dirt. Neither balcony has an outlet or a hose spigot. Neighbors below me have larger balconies so I’ve been avoiding taking a bucket to it and scrubbing but swiffer and Mr clean magic erasers can only do so much.
Any ideas or magic portable devices out there? Thanks in advance!!

High-pressure washer can push dirt far away from balcony below.

@DrMoishePippik  Should ad most dirt, some will drip down.

There are some cement surface coverings like epoxy that might fill in the pock marks, leaving the surface more smoother.

Just how big are these balconies? How do the other neighbors clean theirs?

@crip659, just use sprayer when downstairs neighbors aren't home -- they'll assume that birds left any droppings. ;-)
